# Missing fourth name in standard visitor visa application for UK

Tags: visas, money

All my official documents (passport included) show my name in this format:

First-Second-Third-Last name

Except my inheritance notification and it shows my name in this format:

First-Second-Third-Fourth-Last name

So the Fourth name isn't mentioned in any official documents except my inheritance notification. Would this cause a problem in proving my financial situation during Visa application? Kindly note that the first name and last name are correct in all papers but that fourth name isn't mentioned in all other papers

Comment: If the inheritance notification matches a deposit on your bank account this should, in my own opinion, be enough to demonstrate that all the documents relate to you.

Comment: problem is that notification only states who the inheritors are and what percentage they get not a definite amount

Comment: Is this really in any way related to Suriname (as the tag implies) or was that a confusion with “surname”?

Comment: If the notification doesn’t state an actual amount, I’m not sure what purpose it serves in your application. What do you expect the visa officer who reads it to learn from such a document?

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't be an issue. Plenty of people have extra names that they use but which won't be mentioned in their passport. I presume the inheritance letter also includes other details such as your date of birth so it should be trivial to match you as the right person.